# How to Rotate ImageButton According to camera Rotation?

Tags: android, layout, camera

Im making a custom camera layout. which has a framelayout and imagebutton. I want to rotate this button according to the camera rotation. so whenever I rotate camera in Image button should face the right direction.
But I couldn't figure it out how to do this. Here is my code...

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        // Get an instance of the WindowManager
        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

        setContentView(R.layout.camera_layout);


        btnCapture = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);       
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout camPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        camPreview.addView(mPreview);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I do jot really understand the problem. When the user rotates the device (camera) your Activity is destroyed and a new instance is created with the new screen layout. Your button should be upwards as expected.

Comment: @jboi no, my layout is fixed landscape. but what Im looking for is when I rotate the camera 90*/180*/270* then my capture button should be rotate as well..